# Extract innerHtml out of body tag using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am parsing html using jsoup and want to extract innerHtml inside of body tag

so far I tried and use document.body.childern().outerHtml; but its giving only html element  and skipping floating text(not wrapped within any html tag) inside of body

```
private String getBodyTag(final Document document) {
        return document.body().children().outerHtml();
}
```

**Input:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>questions to improve formatting and clarity.</div>
       <h3>Guided Mode</h3> 
       some sample raw/floating text
    </body>
</html>
```

**Expected:**

```
<div>questions to improve formatting and clarity.</div>
<h3>Guided Mode</h3> 
some sample raw/floating text
```

**Actual:**

```
<div>questions to improve formatting and clarity.</div>
<h3>Guided Mode</h3>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this:

```
private String getBodyTag(final Document document) {
    return document.body().html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning `document.body.innerHtml;` instead, so it would return everything inside the body tag, including the text outside any tag.

As far as I know, the way you are trying to accomplish it is not working because the "raw text" is not considered a child.